# Could you help me to fix the car? Or without the preposition?

Tags: prepositions

could you tell me which is the right way to construct this sentence:

> A. Could you help me fix the car?
>
> B. Could you help me **to** fix the car?

Or perhaps both? What is the rule that governs the use or the preposition "to" in the sentence?

Comment: Either is valid; the first is more common, but I have also heard the latter.

Comment: @AntonSherwood So what is valid?

Comment: Was I unclear? Both.

Answer (score 1):

A is the correct sentence. The grammar of sentence B may be correct but it is unnatural usage. I don't know of any specific rules to help with prepositions, because English doesn't have consistent rules for everything. Learning the correct use of prepositions comes from listening and practice. If anybody else can find a rule that has few exceptions, let us know.